# Modified version of Conway's Game of Life, ratio of alive cells becomes $\pi$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, cellular-automata

I saw someone comment on a YouTube video with a weird result they had gotten, and then replicated that result myself. It is the following:

Consider the following modification on Conway's Game of Life:

On even steps, nothing changes: regular Game of Life rules hold. But on odd steps, cells can't die. So the rule for creating an alive cell (exactly $3$ alive neighbors) still holds, but no alive cell dies.

When I programmed this in Python in bounded grids (the largest I tried was $10000\times1000$), something peculiar seemed to happen: the ratio alive cells/all cells seemed to, after a certain amount of steps, oscillate between $\frac1\pi$ (on odd steps) and $\frac2{3\pi}$ (on even steps).

So I wonder: with this version of Conway's Game of Life on an infinite grid, are there (necessarily never-repeating) patterns of which the ratio of alive cells to all cells are $\frac1\pi$ and $\frac2{3\pi}$ such that they map to each other under these rules? And moreover, why do other patterns seem to converge to these patterns?

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{\pi}$ ? How good is your approximation, how many decimals do you match the value?

Comment: @caduk I multiplied the ratio by either $\pi$ or $3\pi/2$. For the even steps, this number was between $0.99$ and $1.01$ (so within $1\%$ accuracy), and for the odd steps this number was between $0.98$ and $1.02$ (so within $2\%$ accuracy)